# class spesfication ADTbag.h, driver

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm fairly new in learning C++. I'm confused and any help will be appreciated. I was given (main.cpp) and (ADTbag.h) in class and told to complete the class implementation ("ADTbag.cpp") With a teacher having a language problem it been really hard to learn anything coming from the professor. My question is are the two (main.cpp) & (ADTbag.h) to be combined? so confused: I just need a for dummy explanation on how to handle this misery.  Below is the code that were given in class:

```
#include "ADTbag.h"

#include<string>

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


void displayBag(ArrayBag<string>& bag)
{
cout << "The bag contains "<< bag.getCurrentSize() << " items:\n";

vector<string> bagItems=bag.toVector();

int numberOfEntries=(int)bagItems.size();

for (int i=0; i<numberOfEntries; i++)
{
    cout <<bagItems[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
}

void main() {

ArrayBag<string> bag;

cout << "Testing the array-based bag:" <<endl;

if (bag.isEmpty())

cout << "The initial bag is empty.\n";

displayBag(bag);

string items[]={"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "one", "two"};

cout << "Add 7 items to the bag:" <<endl;

for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
   {

    bag.add(items[i]);
}
displayBag(bag);
cout << "The string \"one\" occurs " << bag.getFrequencyOf("one") << " times.\n";

cout << "The string \"two\" occurs " << bag.getFrequencyOf("two") << " times.\n";

cout << "The string \"three\" occurs " << bag.getFrequencyOf("three") << " time.\n";

cout << "The string \"seven\" occurs " << bag.getFrequencyOf("seven") << " time.\n";

cout<< "Remove string \"one\" ...\n";

bag.remove("one");

displayBag(bag);

cout<< "Remove string \"two\" ...\n";

bag.remove("two");

displayBag(bag);

if (bag.contains("three"))

    cout << "The bag contains the string \"three\".\n";
else 
    cout << "The bag does NOT contain the string three.\n";

if (bag.contains("seven"))

    cout << "The bag contains the string \"seven\".\n";
else 
    cout << "The bag does NOT contain the string \"seven\".\n";

cout << "Delete all items fron the bag. \n";

bag.clear();

displayBag(bag);
```

}

ALSO when I put it in the compiler to get started the "#include ADTbag.h" is underlined in red giving an error "can't open source file "bag.h"
The driver is given below:

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_BAG
#define _ARRAY_BAG

#include <vector>

const int MAX_LIST=20;  // Maximum capacity of the bag

using namespace std;

template <class ItemType>
class ArrayBag
{
  public:

    ArrayBag();  //default constructor. Create an empty list.

    bool isEmpty() const;  // test if the bag is empty

    int getCurrentSize() const; // get the number of items in the bag

    bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
    //Insert the newEntry into a bag that is not full.  Place it right after the last item in the array.

    bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
    //Remove an item from the bag that matches the newEntry

    int getFrequencyOf (const ItemType& anEntry) const;
    // To count the number of times a given object occurs in a bag.

    bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
    // To test if the item "anEntry" is in the bag.

    void clear(); // Remove all items from the bag.

    vector <ItemType> toVector() const; 
    // Get the entries that are in a bag and return them within a vector.

  private:

     ItemType items[MAX_LIST];  // Array of bag items

     int size; // current count of bag items
};
#endif
```

Comment: Both code-snippets are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add source code of ADTbag.h (as I understand, both your source codes are the same). But basic theory is very simple:

1. Put all three files (main.cpp, ADTbag.h and ADTbag.cpp) in one directory,
2. Add line `#include "ADTbag.h"` in ADTbag.cpp and add implementation of all functions from (ADTbag.h) in ADTbag.cpp.

So you ADTbag.cpp will be like this:

```
#include "ADTbag.h"

ArrayBag::ArrayBag()
{
  size = 0; // initialize empty list
}

bool ArrayBag::isEmpty() const
{
  return (size == 0); // return true if list is empty
}

int ArrayBag::getCurrentSize() const
{
  return size; // return size of the list
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for ur input I have edited the question and added the 2 source code. As on where to start with the ADTbag.cpp that were im lost, do I just copy & paste the two given files together and work from there or what is really ask of me?

Comment: You have to create ADTbag.cpp with implementation of all functions, which described in ADTbag.h. I'll edit my answer to show you example (see above).